# Undefined Variable Warning in PHP

Tags: php, forms, warnings

So I've been doing this school project and need to make it so I can edit whatever is in the table. Whenever i click on "Edit" it redirects me correctly but in the form it says there is an undefined variable eventhough that variable is used pretty much everywhere.
Here is some code of the table:

```
<table style='margin-left:auto ; margin-right:auto;'>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Zeit</th>
        <th>Datum</th>
        <th>Titel</th>
        <th>Inhalt</th>
        <th>Ort</th>
        </tr>

<?php
if($stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM terminkalender")) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $zeilen = $stmt->num_rows();
    $stmt->close();
}else {
    $zeilen = 0;
}
if($zeilen > 0) {
    //nur wenn Einträge, dann ausgeben
    if($stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM terminkalender ORDER BY zeit,datum DESC")) {
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($id,$name,$zeit,$datum,$ort,$titel,$inhalt);
        $stmt->store_result();
        //Ausgabe starten
        while($stmt->fetch()){
            echo "<tr>";
?>
                <td><?php echo $id ;?></td>
                <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($name) ;?></td>
                <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($datum) ;?></td>
                <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($zeit) ;?></td>
                <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($ort) ;?></td>
                <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($titel) ;?></td>
                <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($inhalt); ?></td>
                <td><a href='edit.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>'>Edit</a></td>
                <td><a href='delete.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>'>Delete</a></td>
<?php 
            echo "</tr>" ;
        
        }
    }
}
?>

</table>
```

and here for the edit.php file:

```
<?php

include("./config/connect.inc.php");

$id = $_GET['id']; // get id through get string

$result=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM terminkalender WHERE id=$id");

if(isset($_POST['update'])) {

    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $datum=$_POST['datum'];
    $zeit=$_POST['zeit'];
    $ort=$_POST['ort'];
    $titel=$_POST['titel'];
    $inhalt=$_POST['inhalt'];
    $result = "UPDATE terminkalender 
                    SET name='$name',
                        datum='$datum',
                        zeit='$zeit',
                        ort='$ort',
                        titel='$titel',
                        inhalt='$inhalt' 
                        WHERE id=$id";
    header("location: ausgabe.php");
}
?>
<form name="form" method="POST" action="edit.php">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" Required>
  <input type="date" name="datum" value="<?php echo $datum; ?>" Required>
  <input type="time" name="zeit" value="<?php echo $zeit; ?>" Required>
  <input type="text" name="ort" value="<?php echo $ort; ?>" Required>
  <input type="text" name="titel" value="<?php echo $titel; ?>" Required>
  <input type="text" name="inhalt" value="<?php echo $inhalt; ?>" Required>
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>">
  <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update">
</form>
```

Ẁould be really awesome if anyone could help. Thanks is advance!

Comment: Can you show the actual text of the error message.

Comment: Can you share the exact warning you're getting please?

Comment: You're never executing the `UPDATE` query.

Comment: <br /><b>Warning</b>:  Undefined variable $ort in <b>/opt/lampp/htdocs/8AI/termindatenbank/edit.php</b> on line <b>46</b><br />  this shows up in all the input boxes besides the date and time

Comment: Which line is line 46?

Comment: The one with the form input for ort

Comment: You only set `$ort` when `$_POST['update']` is set. When you load the edit page the first time, it won't be set.

Comment: The variable won't be set unless you've already submitted the form. You need an isset() to control it

Comment: You could also give all the variables default values before the `if`

Comment: They should already have values because they come from my database. How do I make it use them?

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: They don't come from your database. Your code tries to take them from $_POST (i.e. the submitted form data), but only when the form was just submitted - which in itself is logical...what's not logical is then proceeding to try and use them regardless of that. There's no other code which tries to populate the variables

Comment: Putting a query into a string variable does not a database access make!

Comment: Ok yes I get that, but what am I supposed to put in there for it to use my database data. Also, will protect it from SQL Injection as soon as I have figured out this problem.

Comment: P.s. the fact you read them from the database in a separate script is irrelevant... That's a separate script responding to a separate request. They might as well be in separate universes too, as far as PHP is concerned

Comment: _Some effort at_ Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: `what am I supposed to put in there `...well in the first script you already showed you know how to write some code to read from the database, so how about basing it on that?

Comment: Okay, tahnk you, been really overthinking this a little.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try using isset function of php to check if that variable contains a value or not for more details check:-https://www.stechies.com/notice-undefined-variable-in-php/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).